# Making .git repo visible in Win7?

Tags: windows-7

I was a bit worried when my .git repo didn't show up although my .gitattributes and ignore did. I quickly realized it was simply hidden (but why not the other two files?), so I changed my folder options to show hidden and system files, but it still doesn't show up. Anyone know the proper magic incantation for Win7?

Comment: I don't remember there should be a tag which show system hidden files try to enable it.

Comment: Yes, that is the one I turned off.no change that I could see.